# How to solve the indefinite integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

The integral :-

$$\int x^m \ln(a+x) \,dx.$$

(Also what is $m$ is not an integer, just an arbitrary real number?)
I have found the integral in the book gradshteyn and ryzhik of which this is a special case. I tried integral by parts for $a=0$ it follows trivially but for the other case please help to find the integral?

Comment: Perhaps you could do $u=a+x$ and then expand $x^m=(u-a)^m$ by the binomial theorem.

Comment: Oh yes thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use integration by parts and note that
$$\frac{x^{m+1}}{a+x}=\sum_{k=0}^m(-a)^kx^{m-k}+\frac{(-a)^{m+1}}{a+x}$$

Answer (score 1):

With one step of by-parts integration (on $x^m$), you get rid of the logarithm and reduce to an incomplete Beta integral. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function (check the fifth property and the incomplete function).

This indirectly proves that for general $m$ there is no closed-form expression.

Answer (score 1):

we have:
$$I=\int x^m\ln(a+x)dx$$
now with $u=\ln(a+x)$ we get:
$$I=\int(e^u-a)^me^uu\,du$$
now using integration by parts:
$$I=\frac{u(e^u-a)^{m+1}}{m+1}-\int\frac{(e^u-a)^{m+1}}{m+1}du$$
now try using binomial expansion. One way of doing it would be by writing:
$$(e^u-a)^{m+1}=e^{(m+1)u}(1-ae^{-u})^{m+1}$$